# Error when creating plpgsql function with if then statement

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, if-statement, plpgsql

I am trying to create this PostgreSQL function:

```
create or replace function sp_get_user_activity(
        begindate date = null,
    enddate date = null)
returns table ( 
    page varchar(75)) as
$body$
begin
    return query
    if begindate is not null and enddate is not null then
        begin
        select page from log_pg where begindate >= created and endate <= created;
        end;
    else
        if begindate is not null then
            begin
            select page from log_pg where begindate >= la.created_on;
            end;
        end if;
        if enddate is not null then
            begin
            select page from log_pg where endate <= created;
            end;
        end if;
    end if;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

I want to create a function that gets page names from a table, either the function can except a begin date and end date, or just an end date or just a begin date.

The error message I'm getting when trying to create the function is and is referring to the very first "if" statement (line 9 in the code I cut/pasted above)

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "if"
> LINE 14:  if begindate is not null and enddate is not null then
>           ^
>
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at or near "if"
> SQL state: 42601
> ```

Tried googling the error code for but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_get_user_activity(begindate date = null
                                               ,enddate   date = null)
RETURNS TABLE (page varchar(75)) AS
$func$
BEGIN

IF begindate IS NOT NULL AND enddate IS NOT NULL THEN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT l.page FROM log_pg l WHERE l.created BETWEEN begindate AND enddate;

ELSIF begindate IS NULL THEN
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT l.page from log_pg l where l.created >= enddate;

ELSE
   RETURN QUERY
   SELECT l.page FROM log_pg l WHERE l.created <= begindate;
END IF;

END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

- `RETURN QUERY` has to be followed by a `SELECT` statement. You can't use an `IF` block instead. That's the immediate cause of the error message.
- Do not start separate code blocks (`begin .. end;`) without need. They cost performance and eat transaction IDs. Hardly ever necessary in plpgsql.
- Simplify your logic. If one of both `IS NULL`, you can simplify ..
- Typos in `endate` and `created_on`. Illegal table qualification in `la.created_on`.
- You *must* table-qualify column names that would conflict with parameter names (`SELECT l.page FROM log_pg l ...`). Your `OUT` parameter `page` is visible everywhere in the function body. Would conflict with the column name `page`. As an alternative, you might avoid conflicting parameter names.

This single SQL statement would do the same, btw:

```
SELECT page FROM log_pg
WHERE (begindate >= created OR begindate IS NULL)
AND   (enddate <= created OR enddate IS NULL);
```

You can wrap it into another plpgsql function or a simple SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sp_get_user_activity(begindate date = null
                                               ,enddate   date = null)
  RETURNS SETOF varchar(75) AS
$func$
SELECT page FROM log_pg
WHERE (begindate >= created OR begindate IS NULL)
AND   (enddate <= created OR enddate IS NULL)
$func$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Requires Postgres 9.1 or later. In older version you'd have to use positional parameters in SQL functions (`$1`, `$2`).

Comment: thank you very much for the feedback erwin.  your approach is much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You have problem with following line:

```
return query
```

If you erase it it will fix the error.